# Doctrine 2 - Updating a user password without the user being logged in

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I am using Doctrine 2 in Zend framework.
What I want is to update a user password, without the user being logged in. Is this the right way to do it in entity class?

```
public function updatePassword($userId, $new_pass, $em){
    $em->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger( new \Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger()); 
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $q  = $qb->update('\Application\User\Entity\User', 'u')
            ->set('u.password', $qb->expr()->literal($new_pass))
            ->where('u.userId = ?1')
            ->setParameter(1, "$userId")
            ->getQuery();
    $p = $q->execute();
    return $p;     

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entity class should never utilize the entity manager. The entity class is just a data storage.

User entity class:

```
namespace Entity;

class User {
    // ...

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = some_hash_algorythm($password);
        return $this;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Your controller or whereever you want to update a user's password:

```
$repo = $em->getRepository('Entity\User');
$user = $repo->find($userId);
$user->setPassword($newPassword);
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

This divides the data storage from actual persistence layer.

If you do not like to have the code in place and want to have it in a central place look in doctrine's documentation for custom repository classes (they are aware of the entity manager and there for "table-actions")

Comment: I used the following :
      `$repo = $em->getRepository('Application\User\Entity\UserDetails');
      $user = $repo->findBy(array('userId' => 12)); 
        $user->setPassword('123');
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush(); `
I am able to get the $user details through the fetch but unable to set the password.
Errors shows as "Call to a member function setPassword() on a non-object". I have the set method defined in the entity class. Is there something that i am missing ?

Comment: `find()` and `findBy()` will return null/false if no matching record could be found. The error message indicates that you get a null/false value (at least no object... This should be the only situation where you get no object as far as I know).

Comment: but am getting an object
`Array ( [0] => Application\User\Entity\UserDetails Object ( [id:protected] => 14 [password:protected] => e09c80c42fda55f9d992e59ca6b3307d [firstName:protected] => Abhilash [lastName:protected] => v [firmName:protected] => myFirm [employeeId:protected] => 4765 [emailAddress:protected] => abhilashv@myfirm.com [userId:protected] => 12 ) )`
and am able to run the get/setter methods if i create an object of the entity class and call with it.

Comment: Ah... You got an array because `findBy()` could return more then one object - If you query for the primary key `find()` is the better solution and gives you just one return object. You could do `$user[0]->setPassword($newPassword)` if you insist on using `findBy()`